# Ignoring NA_real_ when calculating with group_by

Tags: r, group-by

I need to do some calculations regarding rows with a same ID (mean, max and sum)

For instance, from all individuals in a same family, which one has the greatest education level:

`yst` = Years of study of this individual

`idf` = Family identification number for this individual

`maxyst` = Years of study of this most educated person in this individual's family

I tried to use mutate() and group_by(), but when there is one NA_real_ row the whole group gets NA. What I want to do is to ignore any idf in which ALL rows are is.na(yst). But if I have at least one !is.na(yst), I wish to ignore all the NA and keep the calculation within the valid rows in that idf.

This is my current code:

```
df %<>% 
  mutate(df, yst = anosest) %>%
  mutate(df, yst = case_when(
    is.na(anosest) ~ 0,
    TRUE ~ yst)) %>%
  group_by(idf) %>%
  mutate(maxyst = max(yst)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Tried a lot of different approaches using a combination of logical values, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: You are not using `na.rm = TRUE` in `max` i.e. `max(yst, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: In addition, your `mutate` statements seems to have syntax issues. i.e `df %<>% mutate(yst = anosest) %>% mutate(yst = ....)` the `df` is already passed in from the `df %<>%..`

Comment: I thought that na.rm = TRUE would ignore ALL NAs. I need to control the groups that there is no valid values. For instance: If `idf` nº 777 has all its rows with `yst = NA`, it needs to be attributed a NA_real_ value.

Comment: Sure. `na.rm = TRUE` ignores all NA. The `max(NA_real_,na.rm=T)` will come out `Inf`. You'd have to add a second set of logic `ifelse(is.infinite(...)|is.nan(...), NA_real_, ...)`.

Comment: Another option would be to do an `ifelse(all(is.na(yst)),NA_real_,max(yst,na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: Yes!! That will do. Though I tried something similar using `case_when()` and it didn't work. Maybe I was using the wrong code.